# destructors on gc-ed lua objects

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

I know that Lua is gc-ed. I know that Lua can deal with c objects via userdata.

Here is my question: is there anyway to register a function so that it's called when a C userdata object is gc-ed by lua? [Basically a destructor].

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a [metamethod](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) called [`__gc`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10.1) specifically for this purpose. See [Chapter 29 - Managing Resources](http://www.lua.org/pil/29.html) of [Programming in Lua (PIL)](http://www.lua.org/pil/index.html) for more details.

The following snippet creates a [metatable](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) and registers a `__gc` metamethod callback:

```
  luaL_newmetatable(L, "SomeClass");

  lua_pushcfunction(L, some_class_gc_callback);
  lua_setfield(L, -2, "__gc");
```